# How to use f:ajax in Facelets with JSF2?

Tags: ajax, events, jsf, facelets, validation

I am trying to use the f:ajax tag to fire my validators on an inputText box but I am not having any luck. It just doesn't seem to fire the validators. But the validators do fire on form submit.

This is what I am using.

---

```
<td>
  <h:inputText id="email" value="#{contactInfo.email}">
    <f:validator validatorId="com.tcs.trn.validator.EmailValidator"></f:validator>
    <f:validator validatorId="com.tcs.trn.validator.TcsEmailValidator"></f:validator>
    <f:ajax execute="@this" event="blur" render="emailMessage"></f:ajax>
  </h:inputText>
</td>
<td>
  <h:message for="email" warnClass="warningMessage" errorClass="errorMessage" id="emailMessage"></h:message>
</td>
```

---

Request Header

```
    Request URL:http://localhost:9080/JSF2Template/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN=y4ftx6y5q; JSESSIONID=0000N5Uz-oCoU910GNVdCP3M8jc:-1
Host:localhost:9080
Referer:http://localhost:9080/JSF2Template/login/userDetails.xhtml
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
ln:javax.faces
stage:Development
Response Headersview source
Content-Language:en-US
Content-Type:application/x-javascript
Date:Thu, 14 Mar 2013 19:32:10 GMT
Expires:Thu, 14 Mar 2013 19:32:10 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 14 Mar 2013 18:33:59 GMT
Server:WebSphere Application Server/7.0
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

This was resolved by adding this to the head. The script link was showing up by default but this actually allowed it to work for some reason.

```
<h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" />
```

Comment: Any JS errors in browser's JS console?

Comment: @BalusC Failed to load resource http://localhost:9080/JSF2Template/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development Uncaught ReferenceError: jsf is not defined userDetails.xhtml:38


 So how do I setup the javascript resources for the ajax with JSF?

Comment: What response did the server return on that resource? (or, simpler put, what do you see when you enter that URL in browser's address bar?). Note that you do by default not need to configure anything, expect of ensuring that you're using `<h:head>` instead of `<head>` (which is in your case apparently already fine). Your concrete problem is caused by bad environment. E.g. an overzealous servlet filter which is unintentionally manipulating resource requests, or overly restrictive authentication/security settings which unintentionally also covers resource requests, etcetera.

Comment: @BalusC when I put the link into the browser it returns what seems like the proper js resource however I am seeing jsf.js.xhtml instead of what I assume should just be jsf.js? Is my webXML servlet mappings somehow adding the .xhtml?

Comment: That's not a problem. Let's go back to the "Failed to load resource" step. What response exactly did the server return? Why exactly did it fail to load the resource? Check the HTTP traffic monitor (the Net/Network tab) for the actual response code, headers and body.

Comment: @BalusC updated question with header information

Comment: And that produced a "Failed to load resource"? Sorry, I don't see any odd things there. Did you check that while requesting the JSF page? (and thus not while requesting the resource independently)

Comment: @BalusC Is it possible that my web.xml servlet mapping of *.xhtml is grabbing this resource and trying to process it as a facelet? I tried changing it to *.jsf and my pages to .jsf but it breaks something giving me a massive stack trace when trying to access pages.

Comment: Mapping is not the problem. The file extension has no influence in how the browser parses the response body, only the `Content-Type` header has.

Comment: @BalusC The Response body seems to be empty when the browser does the get request. The head seems fine though. 

If I copy the link into the address bar the content body comes fine when putting in the get parameters after the ?. Without the get parameters it fails to return anything.

Comment: As per your `<h:outputScript>` solution. This is strange. What JSF impl/version are you using? Mojarra or MyFaces? What JSF project stage have you set in `web.xml`? To exclude a cache from being the cause, what if you remove the `<h:outputScript>` now it works and retry without it? MyFaces is namely known to agressively cache Facelets files when project stage is not set to development. Only a server restart would reload the Facelets files.

Comment: @BalusC The Project Stage is set to development. I am using MyFaces 2.0.9. Removing the h:outputScript will cause the browser to fail to retrieve the resource. It will still work if it gets the resource from its cache. After a ctrl-f5 it reverts to the old behavior.

Comment: Can you please check the difference in the generated HTML output and report back?